# Filter and assign object from an array to another object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have specific object that I need to get from another array which is the `hexCode`

This is the data that I'm filtering

```
{
  dateCreated: "2019-10-30 08:29:54 PM" 
   hexCode: "#ed4c67" 
  id: 1 
  leaveTag: "Vacation Leave" 
  leaveTagColor: "Bara Red"
}
{
  dateCreated: "2019-10-30 08:30:05 PM" 
  hexCode: "#ea2027"
     id: 2 
  leaveTag: "Sick Leave"
     leaveTagColor: "Red Pigment"
}
```

This is the data where I want to insert the hexCode. And mapping the `leaveType` to compare it with the data above. Will that be possible?

```
{
  leaveType: "Emergency Leave"
  email: "sfe.bruce.logan@gmail.com"
  hexCode: ???
}
{
  leaveType: "Sick Leave"
  email: "sfe.bruce.logan@gmail.com"
  hexCode: ???
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach using just array map

```js
const obj1 = [{
  dateCreated: "2019-10-30 08:29:54 PM",
  hexCode: "#ed4c67",
  id: 1,
  leaveTag: "Vacation Leave",
  leaveTagColor: "Bara Red"
},
{
  dateCreated: "2019-10-30 08:30:05 PM",
  hexCode: "#ea2027",
  id: 2,
  leaveTag: "Sick Leave",
  leaveTagColor: "Red Pigment"
}]


const obj2 = [{
  leaveType: "Emergency Leave",
  email: "sfe.bruce.logan@gmail.com",
  hexCode: null
},
{
  leaveType: "Sick Leave",
  email: "sfe.bruce.logan@gmail.com",
  hexCode: null
}]
const result = obj2.map(item => {
  const findedHex = obj1.find(o2item => o2item.leaveTag == item.leaveType)
  item.hexCode = findedHex && findedHex.hexCode || null;
  return item;

})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: why filter[0] if you can use .find(). Filter returns all values and check every item in the array,. Find is more optimal since it stops when the first match is found

Comment: @DhananjaiPai yes i agree better approach with find.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I like your answer since I have minimal changes in my code to yours and it works like charm!

Comment: Cheers!! @AlyssaReyes ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do a lookup like below, but the time complexity is higher in this case (though higher readability and no space complexity)

Or you can create a Map of type `leaveType : hexCode` from first data array and then use the Map to find the corresponding value and fill the second array. Check @CodeManiac's answer for this approach.

```js
const data = [{
  dateCreated: "2019-10-30 08:29:54 PM",
  hexCode: "#ed4c67",
  id: 1,
  leaveTag: "Vacation Leave",
  leaveTagColor: "Bara Red"
},
{
  dateCreated: "2019-10-30 08:30:05 PM",
  hexCode: "#ea2027",
  id: 2,
  leaveTag: "Sick Leave",
  leaveTagColor: "Red Pigment"
}]

const arr = [{
  leaveType: "Emergency Leave",
  email: "sfe.bruce.logan@gmail.com",
},
{
  leaveType: "Sick Leave",
  email: "sfe.bruce.logan@gmail.com"
}]

arr.forEach(leave => {
 const matchedLeave = data.find(lv => lv.leaveTag === leave.leaveType);
 if(matchedLeave) {
   leave.hexCode = matchedLeave.hexCode;
 }
});
 
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate your answer but I'll use David's answer :)

Comment: No worries, though I had answered first :D But then again, its not a contest and happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map` and `map`

- Map `leaveTag` to respective `hexCode`
- Loop over the data check if the `leaveType` exists in `Map` if exists use the value from `Map` else keep it the original value

```js
const data = [{dateCreated: "2019-10-30 08:29:54 PM",hexCode: "#ed4c67",id: 1,leaveTag: "Vacation Leave",leaveTagColor: "Bara Red"}, {dateCreated: "2019-10-30 08:30:05 PM",hexCode: "#ea2027",id: 2,leaveTag: "Sick Leave",leaveTagColor: "Red Pigment",}]
const desiredFormat = [{leaveType: "Emergency Leave",email: "sfe.bruce.logan@gmail.com",hexCode: ''}, {leaveType: "Sick Leave",email: "sfe.bruce.logan@gmail.com",hexCode: ''}]

const mapper = new Map(data.map(({leaveTag,hexCode}) => [leaveTag, hexCode]))

const final = desiredFormat.map(({ hexCode, ...rest }) => {
  return {
    ...rest,
    hexCode: mapper.get(rest.leaveType) || hexCode
  }
})
console.log(final)
```

Comment: Good job, but too much destructuring seriously harms readability. `x => [x.leaveTag, x.hexCode]` is shorter and far more understandable than  `({leaveTag,hexCode}) => [leaveTag, hexCode])`

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate your answer but I'll use David's answer :)